# How to use javascript variables vales in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

Hi i have facebook login code i want to use javascript varibles values on code behind.I can use by saving them in hidden field but there is no button click so page is not postback.

here is my code:

```
<script>
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));

    // Init the SDK upon load
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '550050651719081', // App ID
            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
                var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture";
                FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                    **document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;

                    document.getElementById('Email').innerHTML = me.email;
                    document.getElementById('profileImg').src = uid;**
                })

            } 
        });

    }
</script>
<h1>
Facebook Login Authentication Example</h1>
<div id="auth-status">
<div id="auth-loggedout">
<div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" scope="email,user_checkins">Login with Facebook</div>
</div>
<div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
Name: <b><span id="auth-displayname"></span></b>(<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)<br />
Email: <b><span id="Email"></span></b><br />
Profile Image: <img id="profileImg" />
</div>
</div>
```

code is working properly but i want to get name,email and uid on code behind also.

Comment: I don't think you can access javascript variables in the code behind. If you can't you'll have to have some kind of event to access the values from the hidden fields...

Comment: can i use ajax posting?

Answer (score 1):

You have send it one way or another to the server:
Either

1) directly via AJAX and catch it on the other side with an [MVC-Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

2) indirectly e.g via [Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386416%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and PostBack.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hiddenfield server control to hold values that will be accessible on postback if using WebForms.

If using MVC, you can add properties to a view model and use the `Html.HiddenFor` helper, which will be accessible by JavaScript.

You could use ajax though, start [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). This will allow you to essentially do it behind the scenes to the user and allow transform during and after the response is fetched. Of course, you would have to write the server side code to catch and process this request.

Comment: i am using webforms but i have no server control so what i can do??

Comment: use the `<asp:HiddenField />` control, as long as it has the attribute `runat="server"` you will be able to access it from the code behind